# What's that Seattle Fast-Food joint?

Tags: product-identification, shadowrun

I know that, when reading through some splatbooks, I found a write-up on some Seattle fast-food restaurant.  The food was horrible, the service was lousy, but everyone liked to meet there because the food was cheap and the place was safe.  There were weapon detectors in the doorframes, the tables and chairs were low-grade transparent plastic that were useless in a fight and couldn't conceal any movements under the table, and the whole thing was surrounded by massive reinforced concrete planters (usually with dead plants in them) that were more intended as deterrents to vehicle impacts than any sort of aesthetics.

Problem is, now that I need to use it, I can't FIND it.  I don't remember if it was a 2nd or 3rd edition book, though probably 2nd...

Anyone remember the name of the place, and what book it was in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fast food place you are looking for probably is **McHugh**. They have paranoid security measures, the food is rather average (and "average" is not a good thing in SR) though.

Google says they were mentioned in the book [Neo-Anarchists' The Guide to Real Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1555601650) which is 2nd Edition, although there is a good chance they were mentioned in 3e as well as 4e. Obviously they survived right into 5e.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the [SR5 Quick Start Rules](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/E-CAT27QSR_SR5-Quick-Start-Rules.pdf) use McHugh's as the central location for the introductory ***Fast Food Fight*** run. It provides decent descriptions and even a map which may be helpful for designing your own run that uses the location. It's also important to recognize that McHugh's is a franchise, so there will be many different convenient McHugh's locations scattered around, each run by different owners with a varying degree of compliance regarding corporate policy.

Comment: nvoight - thank you very much!  That's the one!  And also thank you to Dyndrilliac, I'll try to look that up.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe The upside to the Quick Start Rules is that they are freely available, so all you have to do is click on the link I provided :-)

Comment: @Dyndrilliac In the Sixth World, failing to comply with corporate policy often results in losing your job... and house... and car... and wife... and children... and... I think I may have to write up a disgraced McHugh's manager.

Comment: "They have paranoid security measures, the food is rather average (and "average" is not a good thing in SR) though." Can characters use the restrooms at McHugh without purchasing anything on the menu?